# Как отобразить цикл в блок-схеме

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, блок, блок-схема, диаграммы

Как можно отобразить цикл в блок схеме?

Comment: Возможно [это](http://открытыйурок.рф/статьи/212317/img2.jpg) вам поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл это конструкция состоящая из условия и стрелки перехода в начало цикла. Обычно условие рисуется ромбиком. [Здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) вы можете найти более подробное описание блок-схемы.